# Отключение EventListener когда вводишь input

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть событие keydown, которое работает на все окно.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyUpReaction);
```

И у меня на странице есть любой

```
<input type='text'>
```

Мне необходимо, когда я ввожу input, чтобы keydown не срабатывал, ибо это активирует лишние элементы находящиееся на странице. Как это можно реализовать? Может как-то создать исключение для этого объекта?

Comment: а зачем keydown на всём окне?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у меня есть меню, которое переключается на E Q и должно быть доступно с любой части этой страницы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю насколько такой вариант подойдет, но можно просто добавить проверку на то, какой элемент на данный момент находится в фокусе.

Если `input` в фокусе, то `console.log` не сработает:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  /** если в фокусе input то возвращаем void */
  if (document.activeElement instanceof HTMLInputElement) return; 
  console.log('keydown');
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const keyDownReaction = function(e){
let target = e.target;
console.log(target.nodeName);
if (target.nodeName === 'INPUT') return false;
else console.log('Блин, клавишу нажали!!!');
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownReaction);
```

```html
<input type='text'> Можно давить здесь 
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<textarea атрибуты>
 А можно здесь...
</textarea>
```